# Google Graph - How to add a legend

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having trouble adding a legend to my graph - the legend does render a color representing each line but i am unsure how to put a string value in the legend which identifies each line on the chart. Each series is held in an array called values, so i want a legend for each series in this array. my current code is:

```
            //create data element for the chart
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();   

        //add column to represent time passing
        data.addColumn('string', xAxis)

        //add a new column for each input project
        for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
            data.addColumn('number', '');   
        }

        //add data to each row, a a numeral for the y axis and string for x
        for(var j =0;j<values[0].length-1;j++){
            if(values.length == 2){
                data.addRow(["sample: " + j, values[0][j],values[1][j]]);
            } else if(values.length == 3){
                data.addRow(["sample: " + j, values[0][j],values[1][j],values[2][j]]);
            }else if(values.length == 4){
                data.addRow(["sample: " + j, values[0][j],values[1][j],values[2][j],values[3][j]]);
            }else if(values.length == 5){
                data.addRow(["sample: " + j, values[0][j],values[1][j],values[2][j],values[3][j],values[4][j]]);
            }else {
                data.addRow([dates[j].getMonth()+1  + "-" + dates[j].getFullYear(), values[0][j]]);
            }
        }

        //populate additional iptions
        var options = {
          title: chartTitle,
          hAxis: { slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45 }, 
          chartArea:{
              left: 100, width: '95%'
          },
          legend: {position: 'top'},
          height: 550,
          width: 1450,
          animation:{
              duration: 800,
              easing: 'out',
              startup: true,
            }
        };

        // Create and draw the visualization - change depending on type of chart
        if(darwin.currentContrubutionAction == "LOC"){
            new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('contributorChart')).draw(data, options);
        } else {
            new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('contributorChart')).draw(data, options);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: very worrying that nobody has a solution for this! :) thanks anyway for all who had a read :)